# Solver selection : NonlinearBlockGS vs NewtonSolver

Tags: openmdao

I have two openmdao groups with cyclic dependency between the groups. I calculate the derivatives using Complex step. I have a non-linear solver for the dependency and use SLSQP to optimize my objective function. The issue is with the choice of the non-linear solver. When I use `NonlinearBlockGS` the optimization is successful in 12 iterations. But when I use `NewtonSolver` with `Directsolver` or `ScipyKrylov` the optimization fails (Iteration limit exceeded), even with `maxiter=2000`. The cyclic connections converge, but it is just that the design variables does not reach the optimal values. The difference between the design variables in consecutive iterations is in the order 1e-5. And this increases the iterations needed. Also when I change the initial guess to a value closer to the optimal value it works.

To check further, I converted the model into IDF (by creating copies of coupling variables and consistency constraints) thereby removing the need for a solver. Now the optimization is successful in 5 iterations and the results are similar to the results when `NonlinearBlockGS` is used.

Why does this happen? Am I missing something? When should I use `NewtonSolver` over others? I know that it is difficult to answer without seeing the code. But it is just that my code is long with multiple components and I couldn't recreate the issue with a toy model. So any general insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code, you're right that its hard to give specifics.

Very broadly speaking, Newton can sometimes have a lot more trouble converging than NLBGS (Note: this is not absolutely true, but is a good rule of thumb). So what I would guess is happening is that on your first or second iteration, the newton solver isn't actually converging. You can check this by setting `newton.options['iprint']=2` and looking at the iteration history as the optimizer iterates.

When you have a solver in your optimization, its critical that you also make sure that you [set it to throw an error on non-convergence.](http://err_on_non_converge) Some optimizers can handle this error, and will backtrack on the line search. Others will just die. Either way, its important. Otherwise, you end up giving the optimizer an unconverged case that it doesn't know is unconverged.

This is bad for two reasons. First, the objective and constraints values it gets are going to be wrong! Second, and perhaps more importantly, the derivatives it computes are going to be wrong! You can read the details [in the theory manual,] but in summary the analytic derivative methods that OpenMDAO uses assume that the residuals have gone to 0. If thats not the case, the math breaks down. Even if you were doing full model finite-difference, non-convergenced models are a problem. You'll just get noisy garbage when you try to FD it.[2](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.2.1/theory_manual/total_derivs/total_derivs_theory.html#direct-method)

So, assuming you have set up your model correctly, and that you have the linear solvers set up problems (it sounds like you do since it works with NLBGS), then its most likely that the newton solver isn't converging. Use iprint, possibly combined with [driver debug printing](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.2.1/features/debugging/debugging_drivers.html), to check this for yourself. If thats the case, you need to figure out how to get newton to behave better.

There are some [tips here](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.2.1/features/debugging/newton_solver_not_converging.html) that are pretty general. You could also try using the [armijo line search](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.2.1/features/building_blocks/solvers/backtracking/armijo_goldstein.html), which can often stablize a newton solve at the cost of some speed.

Finally... Newton isn't the best answer in all situations. If NLBGS is more stable, and computational cheaper you should use it. I applaud your desire to get it to work with Newton. You should definitely track down why its not, but if it turns out that Newton just can't solve your coupled problem reliably thats ok too!

Answer (score 0):

the [set it to throw an error on non-convergence](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/advanced_user_guide/analysis_errors/analysis_error.html) is broken on your answer. I have added the link which I think is the right one. Please correct if the linked one is not the one you were thinking to link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).